# sed not parsing variable

Tags: bash, sed

I'm stuck with a bash script here...

I have variables:

```
hostname1="sxxx" hostname2="vbbbb" hostname3="sggg" hostname4="aaa" ...
```

I'm trying to change the 12th line of every files in a folder with the host-name variables.

The files are  `server1.txt server2.txt server3.txt server4.txt ...`

I'm trying to do this with a while loop:

```
i=1
imax=1

while [[ $i -le 20 ]]
do

    sed -i "12s/.*/$hostname$imax/" server$((imax)).txt

    (( i++ ))
    (( imax++ ))

        if [[ imax -eq 21 ]]
            then
                imax=1
        fi

done
```

what I want to do with `sed` is to concatenate the word host-name with imax and then use it as variable.
Maybe with this I'm clear enough:

```
$hostname=hostname$imax; //for exammple 
sed -i "12s/.*/$hostname/" server$((imax)).txt // i need here the variable $hostname to have the content "sxxx"
```

Comment: Any particular reason you have a bunch of separate `hostnameN` variables instead of an array `hostname[N]`? An array would be much easier to work with.

Comment: it's because they are for a gaming server and each server should have separate config file in my case

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I can't imagine why a gaming server would care if your shell script to create config files uses an array with 12 elements vs 12 separate variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You achieve this by using `indirect parameter expansion`,

```
${!var}
```

Here, `var` - is a dynamically generated variable name.

Try this:

```
sed -i "12s/.*/${!hostname}/" server$((imax)).txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ hostname1="sat"
$ i=1
$ hostval="hostname$i"
$ echo ${!hostval}
sat
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the following.  Use change, instead of switch in sed.  Then strong quote my sed, and unquote my variables.

```
for i in {1..20}; do
   eval h='$'hostname$i
   sed -i '12c'$h'' server$i.txt
done
```

Bash 3 and over supports number ranges in a for looop, easier than your while loop.  I also have no idea what you are doing with imax instead of just i, b/c you exit at 20, but change imax value to 1... which it will never use.

edit: b/c I misread

Answer (score -1):

Basically, your problem comes from a variable interpretation.

Try using sed >=4.2.2, should work with your code.